# TFS undoing Promote Candidate Changes

Tags: visual-studio

I am using VS2015 and TFS.
By mistake I have clicked on Promote Candidate Changes for all the excluded files... (.xml,.nupkg, ecc...)

Now, every time I reopen the Solution and go to TFS "pending changes" all these files are listed in the Included Changes.

I can click individually on the folders and choose "Exclude" but that works only for this time... When I close/reopen VS (or the solution) all the files are back on the Included Changes...

How can I restore/undo the Promote Candidate Changes?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could undo the promoting of files, just click "Undo..." in context menu. It will add you files to "Detected adds" list again.

Comment: Thanks, this worked as expected. This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: Clicking undo removes all local changes as well, it doesn't simply demote the files.

Comment: @Cos Wrong, these files typically don't have any "local changes" because they are files TFS automatically detected to ADD to source control. If you promote them then Undoing WILL put them back into detected adds. The only way to get rid of them is to delete them.

Answer (score 1):

You have added these files to source control.  Unfortunately TFS doesn't make removing them from source control as easy.  Here are the steps:

1 - Copy all the files you want to keep to a temporary directory

2 - Open the Source Control Explorer window to the files you want to remove from SC

[image]

3 - Get latest on the files

4 - Delete the file(s) from the Explorer window

[image]

5 - Checkin your changes

6 - Copy the files from your temporary location back to the source folder